# How to prevent action in parent form executing when child form is visible in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a main form, and a floating child form that is non-modal.  The main form has a TAction called DeleteAction that has Delete as it's shortcut.  When the floating form is visible and Delete is pressed, the main form's DeleteAction is executed.

How do I prevent the shortcut passing through the child form to the parent?  I could verify that the child form does not have the focus in the Delete action's OnExecute handler or in the OnUpdate handler of the actions's ActionManager, but I have lots of other actions and would have to duplicate this solution for them too.  I also have other floating forms that can be visible.

This is using Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for focus wouldn't work since pressing Delete on the parent form would result in giving the parent form focus.

```
function AllowActions: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not ChildFloatingForm.Visible;
end;
```

Then on the actions **OnAction** event handler, set it's **Enabled** property to the result of *AllowActions*;

You could also add the following line to the **OnExecute** event handler for the action:

```
if not AllowActions then Exit;
```

I recommend putting the rules about when to allow actions in a function in case you change those rules, and since you said that multiple actions may follow the same rules.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Perhaps there should be a property of the Action like "ParentRequireFocus" or something to control when it gets triggered.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I use:

```
type
  TMyMainForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  public
    function IsShortCut(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean; override;
  end;

function TMyMainForm.IsShortCut(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean;
begin
  // Work around to avoid main form stealing shortcuts from active, non-modal forms.
  if (Screen.ActiveForm <> nil) and (Screen.ActiveForm <> Self) then
    Result := Screen.ActiveForm.IsShortCut(Message)
  else
    Result := inherited;
end;
```

This works for all cases where the focused control is owned, directly or indirectly, by the active form.

There is a rare special case that isn't handled by the above. For example if the popupcontrol of a DevExpress TcxPopupEdit control doesn't have an owner, then it doesn't work since the owner chain from active form to active control is "broken". I usually handle this case by case in the TAction.OnUpdate handler:

```
procedure TMyMainForm.ActionSomeThingUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TAction(Sender).Enabled := (SomeThingSomeThing) and
    // Prevent action from stealing shortcut from edit fields on non-modal forms
    (Screen.ActiveForm is TWhatEverFormThisActionAppliesTo);
end;
```