# How to prevent main menu actions from executing when child form is visible

Tags: delphi, vcl

In an MDI VCL application, when I have a non-modal Form showing, keyboard shortcuts for the MainForm's menu will switch focus to the MainForm and perform menu item actions - which is never what I want.

In earlier versions of Delphi, one could override the MainForm's `IsShortCut()` method (as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36574493/1022775)), but this no longer works in Delphi 10.4.2.

I have tried various permutations of using `OnShortCut` and `IsShortCut()` from `TApplication` and `TForm` without success.

Overriding `IsShortCut()` of a non-MainForm to return true for <kbd>Alt+</kbd> keyboard combinations does work to block the MainForm menus, but it also blocks local hotkeys in the action form, so is not very helpful.

Is there now a better (or any!) way to do this?

Comment: How are these keyboard shortcuts implemented? Using menu items, actions, ... ? And by "keyboard shortcuts", I assume you mean things like `Ctrl+O` assigned to a menu item or action, and not accelerators like `Alt+F`. Typically, you very much *want* such shortcuts to be used even when a MDI child has focus -- indeed, the app shouldn't have many commands available at all if no document is currently opened! For instance, Ctrl+S should save the current document, Ctrl+O should open a new document.

Comment: I interpret "child form" as a MDI child form. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry no, I mean other non-MDI pop-up non-modal windows (which might even cover the main form). The shortcuts are everything from Alt+F to open the File menu to hotkeys associated with specific submenu items.

Comment: If we restrict the attention to shortcuts like Ctrl+O, you can (and should!) use actions (`TActionList`) and have each menu item refer to an action. Then you can use the action's `OnUpdate` to make sure it is disabled when the main form isn't the active form.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when the shortcut is invoked, the main form (or active MDI form) calls the container menu item's `OnClick` before testing for assignments of the shortcuts. So what works for me is enabling the menu item in the menu item's container menu's `OnClick` handler (e.g. for an item on the File menu, set the `OnClick` event for the File menu item itself). E.g. like this

```
procedure TMyForm.FileMenuClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyMenu.Enabled := Screen.ActiveForm = self;  
end;
```

The corresponding shortcut for MyMenu is then not processed by the form, and can be correctly used by the active window.